# How to put single horizontal line at the bottom of details section on crystal report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am trying to make a Table where I need only one horizontal at the bottom of the details section on crystal report but If add a line at the bottom of details section when report is pulled it becomes a table, I don't want rows to be splited by each horizontal line.
Even I selected as "Move to the bottom of the section when Printing" for that horizontal line

Kindly help I am new to crystal reports

Comment: Depending on where you want the line to appear, it must be put either inside group footer, page footer or report footer section...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the horizontal line in your Details section.  Select the line object, right click on it and click "Format Line".  Click the "X2" button next to the "Suppress" checkbox and then enter the following formula.

`Not OnLastRecord`

This formula will now suppress every instance of the horizontal line that is not located in the details section for the last record.